# Where should I put these functions? Inside models.py or inside views.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am developing a web app using Django.
There are few functions like, `get_token`, `get_url` etc to fetch data from the database and also to modify the database.

Where should I put those functions? Inside `views.py` or `models.py`?

Since those functions are interacting with the database directly I am thinking of putting those in the `models.py` file to use those functions as an abstraction.
I would like to know the best practice.

Comment: You need to provide more details of what do they do. A lot of thing would interact with database, but not necessarily all go to models.py.

Comment: @ShangWang get_token(url) checks if the url already exists in the database or not. If yes then it gets the token associated with the url. Otherwise it adds the url to the database with a new token and then return token to the caller.
get_url(token) checks if the token is present in the database or not. If yes, then it fetches the url associated with it from the database and returns.

Comment: There are 2 possibilities: If your caller is in views.py, then put this close to the caller function so when people read your code, they find the function easily. If it's used in many other places, put it in models.py and import that.

Answer (score 2):

- models.py is meant to be used to define Classes (each takes up a
  table in the database).
- views.py contains any functions that are used
  to return django rendered pages. It definitely contains any view functions and other functions that are called within the view.

Since your functions get_token() & get_url(), are processing data (and not creating, modifying or deleting tables), i'd suggest you to put them in the views.py file.

A sample way you might approach this is as below:

**models.py:**

```
class UrlTokenPair(models.Model):
      url = models.models.TextField(blank=True)
      token = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
from app_name.models import UrlTokenPair

def get_token(input_url):
    if UrlTokenPair.objects.filter(url=input_url):
       return UrlTokenPair.objects.get(url=input_url).token
    else:
       new_entry = UrlTokenPair.objects.create(url=input_url)
       new_entry.token = yourAlgoForToken()
       new_entry.save()
       return new_entry.token

def get_url(input_token):
    if UrlTokenPair.objects.filter(token=input_token):
       return UrlTokenPair.objects.get(url=input_token).url
    else:
       new_entry = UrlTokenPair.objects.create(token=input_token)
       new_entry.url = yourAlgoForUrl()
       new_entry.save()
       return new_entry.url
```

You can then call the above functions get_url and get_token in any view function in the views.py file. You can also call them in another .py file by just referring to them as:

```
from app_name.views import get_url, get_token
```